# Need Compact edition of Libav or FFmpeg for working with python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, libav, pytube

I'm building a youtube Video/audio downloader in python which is lite edition. I need functions to convert WebM and m4a to mp3. And also function to merge audio and video. The whole libav /ffmpeg pack seems to be a bit high sized. I can't expect the users to have this pre-installed. So, Is there a way to implement these functionalities in a pythonic way or can we just extract these functions from libav/ffmpeg and pack it for the user.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at `youtube-dl`, how they do it, or maybe `youtube-dl` already serves the script you are trying to build? https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

Comment: But it also requires ffmpeg pre installed in the system. Without ffmpeg it will land an error on post processing.

Comment: There would almost always be a requirement of some pre-installed libraries, even if you write it from scratch. How about, relying on the package managers for installation of the dependent libraries, like `pip` or `brew`?

Comment: Actually I'm building a .exe file so that will obviously pack the dependencies within.So, that I am asking is there any mini version of libav or ffmpeg to just work with audio converting and mixing. I am not familiar with C or C++, so that I couldn't understand the library.

Comment: These libraries might be of help: https://pyav.org/docs/stable/ and https://pypi.org/project/Avpy/

Answer (score 0):

I'm Amin.

I'm building a same app using pytube just like you. But I have the same problem. FFmpeg is about 328 MB and I can't force my users to download that.

There is also another way to use moviepy library that works well but it happens another problem.
I use pyinstaller to extract a .exe file of my app to let anyone run it without having python installed.
And when I use moviepy in my code, pyinstaller doesn't recognize it and throws up an error.

I havn't found any another library for merging video and audio yet :(

But if you want to use moviepy, here is the code:

```
def combine_audio_video(video_name, audio_name, output_name, fps=30):
    import moviepy.editor as mp
    input_video = mp.VideoFileClip(video_name)
    input_audio = mp.AudioFileClip(audio_name)
    final_clip = input_video.set_audio(input_audio)
    final_clip.write_videofile(output_name, fps=fps)
```